# Retrieve Email ID from SharePoint List to Custom Button

Tags: sharepoint-online, custom-list, sharepoint-rest-api

I am having a requirement to get a **Contact** Button on home page that having a functionality, when we click on the button, New email tab opens with email id Example@gmail.com. We should change the email ID Without changing the code.

I created a List and Inter a email id in Title and try to retrieve the email id from REST API, But it didn't work for me.
Below is the code I have used in the new page with **Script Editor WebPart**

**https://XYZ.sharepoint.com/sites/ABC/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('email')/items?$select=Title&$filter=ID eq 2'" />**

Comment: Are you getting any error message? Check in console and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using the `https://XYZ.sharepoint.com/sites/ABC/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('email')/items?$select=Title&$filter=ID eq 2` REST API as the attribute value of the Contact element?

You need to get the title using the REST API firstly, then use its value as the attribute value.

Information about [how to retrieve SharePoint List Items Using Rest API](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/retrieve-sharepoint-list-items-using-rest-api)

To return items from a list using JavaScript, we can also use the `getItemById(id)` function to return a single item, or use the `getItems(query)` function to return multiple items.

[SharePoint Online: Retrieve list items from SharePoint list using JavaScript Object Model (JSOM)](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/37536.sharepoint-online-retrieve-list-items-from-sharepoint-list-using-javascript-object-model-jsom.aspx)

[SharePoint Online List methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.list_methods.aspx)